# How to check if query returned a result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foursquare

I am using Rails 3.2 and I fetch venues from Foursquare. I need to check if any of the venue IDs that I get in return is registered in my database and then return that array. I try to do it this way and it works BUT I get nil (in the array) for all those venues that are not present. What is wrong with my code and is there a better way of doing this so I do not have to do 20 queries (one query against the database for each FQ venue).

```
def index
    client = Foursquare::Base.new(CLIENT_KEY, SECRET_KEY)
    @venues = client.venues.search(:ll => "-33.8670522, 151.1957362")

    output = @venues["nearby"].collect do |venue|
      account = Account.find_by_fq_venue (venue.id) if account.present?
    end

    render :json => output, :status => :success
  end
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up solving it like this:

```
client = Foursquare::Base.new(CLIENT_KEY, SECRET_KEY)
    venues = client.venues.search(:ll => "-33.8670522, 151.1957362")
    ids = venues["nearby"].collect { |venue| venue.id }
    @output = Account.find_all_by_fq_venue (ids)
    render :json => @output, :status => :success
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
account = Account.find_by_fq_venue (venue.id) if account.present?
```

To

```
account = Account.find_by_fq_venue (venue.id) if Account.find_by_fq_venue (venue.id)
```

i am just explaining why it is getting wrong you are using `account` before value assigned to it and hence your if condition always not satisfied and you get an aary of nil.

Better way to do this is
Change

```
output = @venues["nearby"].collect do |venue|
  account = Account.find_by_fq_venue (venue.id) if account.present?
end
```

To

```
output = Account.find(:all, 
                 :conditions =>["fq_venue IN (?)", @venues["nearby"].map(&:id) ])
```

For Rails 3

```
output = Account.where(["fq_venue IN (?)", @venues["nearby"].map(&:id) ])
```

Comment: No that did not do any difference. Why query twice?

Comment: I am using Rails 3.2 isn´t that the old syntax? How can I code that for newest version of Rails?

Comment: Thank you for you help! I have updated my question with my final result. Does it look ok?

Comment: you can use `@output = Account.find_all_by_fq_venue (@venues["nearby"].map(&:id))`

Answer (score 0):

Hi You Try with this.

account=[]

```
output = @venues["nearby"].collect do |venue|
  account << Account.find_by_fq_venue (venue.id) if !venue.id.nil?
end
```

now in account array u will get all the rows.

-- Viji Kumar.